# Cloudflare <> Cloudfront without adding Alternative domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, cross-domain, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare

Connect to cloudflare/or other DNS without adding Alternative domain name in cloudfront

I'm working on project, that uses cloudfront to serve the content, that goes like this

1. Created Cloudfront
2. Added Alternative domain `*.mysite1.com`
3. Connected with source(s3 in this case)

Now want to use it in cloudflare/or any other services
What i did is

1. Created a Record `user.com` in my DNS with CNAME
2. Pointed to `user.mysite1.com`
3. I haven't added in my cloudfront(I think its a extra work)

Now It's serving, beautiful 403 cloud front access deined.

Any ideas, how can i overcome or do things

Comment: Where are you getting 403? have you configured any security or CORS in cloudfront.
Please explain more how you are accessing this content through cloudflare or redirecting.

Comment: What i understood was its not the issue of cloudfare, its the issue of cloudfront we need to add an alternative domain name. But i don't want to do that.